# How to open Save As dialog with default filename pre-filled

Tags: vba

I'm currently using the following to automatically save the output to a specified file.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & Range("E9") & " Perf Eval.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

I need to change it to show the Save As dialog box and pre-fill the filename and extension so the directory can be manually chosen.  I'm trying to use `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` and it displays the dialog box with no filename or file format defined. How can I get it to pre-fill the filename and set the file format?

I've tried using the `InitialFileName` argument as shown below, but it just gives me "compile error expected: ="

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename (InitialFileName:=Range("E9") & " Perf Eval.xlsx")
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename

Comment: I've tried to use the InitialFileName argument, but I get "expected: +" with

`Application.GetSaveAsFilename (InitialFileName:=Range("E9") & " Perf Eval.xlsx")`

Comment: Please update your post with the code you tried - it's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: `GetSaveAsFilename` doesn't save the file - it just returns a file name/path: you still need to perform a `SaveAs`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub fileDialog()
Dim fd As Office.fileDialog
Dim strFile As String
Set fd = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fd
.InitialFileName = "File Name"
If .Show = True Then
strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With
End Sub
```